# Glassfish, Java email and certificate

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, jakarta-mail, antivirus

I've search far and long and can't find the answer.

I'm using Glassfish and want to send an email via our smtp server.

I've obtained the server's certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:587 -starttls smtp > our.cer
```

I've cleaned up the cer file to only contain the certificate data.
I've import it everywhere:

```
keytool -import -alias mail.example.com -file our.cer -keystore c:\Progra~1\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
keytool -import -alias mail.example.com -file our.cer -keystore c:\Progra~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_4\jre\lib\security\cacerts
keytool -import -alias mail.example.com -file our.cer -keystore c:\PROGRA~1\GLASSF~1.0\GLASSF~1\domains\domain1\config\cacerts.jks
```

But I get the following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    ...
    Caused by...
    ...
    Caused by...
    ...
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My code snippet:

```
...
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.example.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "example@example.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "some.password");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"));
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"));
properties.put("mail.smtp.from", "example@example.com"));
properties.put("mail.transport", "smtp"));

...

Authenticator mailAuthenticator = new Authenticator()
{
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),
                        properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));
    }
};
try
{
    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, mailAuthenticator);
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    mimeMessage.setSubject("Hallo world!");
    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.from")));
    mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("example@example.com"));
    mimeMessage.setText("Some text message...");

    Transport transport = session.getTransport(properties.getProperty("mail.transport"));//"smtp"

    int port = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.port"));//587
    transport.connect(properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"),//"mail.example.com"
                    port,
                    properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),//"example@example.com"
                    properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));//Clear text password
    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
    LOG.info("...done sending email");
}
catch (AddressException e)
{
    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while sending email", e);
}
catch (MessagingException e)
{
    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while sending email", e);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while sending email", e);
}
```

I've also tried [Mkyong's suggestion](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) to run InstallCert [(source)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/180292346/InstallCert.java) against the mail server but I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've loaded the certificate in the following additional places:

```
keytool -import -alias mail.example.com -file our.cer -keystore c:\PROGRA~1\GLASSF~1.0\GLASSF~1\domains\domain1\config\keystore.jks
keytool -import -alias mail.example.com -file our.cer -keystore c:\GLASSFISH\config\keystore.jks
keytool -import -alias mail.example.com -file our.cer -keystore c:\GLASSFISH\config\cacerts.jks
```

I've also set these properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:\\GLASSFISH\\config\\keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:\\GLASSFISH\\config\\cacerts.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

I've also switched on debugging for ssl (Glassfish console, server, properties) `javax.net.debug=ssl`.

***It works in a standalone test application (Java SE) but not in Glassfish.***

**UPDATE 2**

Using the `javax.net.debug=ssl` and examining the log out put I can see that even-though I've loaded the certificate "everywhere" or if I point Glassfish to the java keystore, Glassfish is missing this certificate.  The stand alone test app has it:

```
adding as trusted cert:
    Subject: CN=avast! Web/Mail Shield Root, O=avast! Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by avast! antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
    Issuer:  CN=avast! Web/Mail Shield Root, O=avast! Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by avast! antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
    Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x14128fa09c50b64ba6d5c99875872673
    Valid from Wed Feb 04 08:56:17 CAT 2015 until Sat Feb 01 08:56:17 CAT 2025
```

(Note the **Serial number**...)

It seems to be the certificate missing from Glassfish; because the stand alone test app finds it:

```
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
    Version: V3
    Subject: CN=avast! Web/Mail Shield Root, O=avast! Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by avast! antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
    Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

    Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
    modulus: ---8<---
    public exponent: 65537
    Validity: [From: Wed Feb 04 08:56:17 CAT 2015, : Sat Feb 01 08:56:17 CAT 2025]
    Issuer: CN=avast! Web/Mail Shield Root, O=avast! Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by avast! antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
    SerialNumber: [    14128fa0 9c50b64b a6d5c998 75872673]

    ...
```

(Look at the **SerialNumber**...)

***Please help***

Comment: did you manage to get to the "Added certificate to keystore 'jssecacerts' using alias 'localhost-1'" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey dokey!  I've figured it out. Here is how my 5 day journey ended today, in brief...

First I dumped all the certificates from the Java keystore, as it was working using that keystore:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\Progra~1\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts > allJavaCerts.txt
```

Then I dumped all the certificates from the Glassfish keystore, to see if the certificate was correctly imported:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\WORKSP~1\GLASS\config\cacerts.jks > allGFCerts.txt
```

In the Java keystore list I notice that the mail server's certificate was issued by Avast... weird, right?

```
Issuer: CN=avast! Web/Mail Shield Root, O=avast! Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by avast! antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
```

And in the Java keystore list there is a certificate for `Alias name: avastsslscannerroot` but not in the Glassfish keystore list - Thank you [Beyond Compare v3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php)

So I exported the *avastsslscannerroot* certificate from the Java keystore and import it into the Glassfish keystore:

```
keytool -export -keystore c:\Progra~1\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts -alias avastsslscannerroot -file avastsslscannerroot.cer
keytool -import -alias avastsslscannerroot -file avastsslscannerroot.cer -keystore c:\WORKSP~1\GLASS\config\keystore.jks
keytool -import -alias avastsslscannerroot -file avastsslscannerroot.cer -keystore c:\WORKSP~1\GLASS\config\cacerts.jks
```

And now it works...

And then it didn't on the server... After some search I came across this:

```
mail.smtp.ssl.trust="*"
```

Property and it works for us as we are connection from *our* web server to *our* mail server...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your local Virus Protection is [Avast](https://www.avast.com/index).

Your Problem is caused by its so called *Active Protection Shield* which  intercepts SSL traffic and scans it for malicous content. In order to achieve this, Avast has to intercept communication between your Java-Program and the SMTPS-Server. For Details see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72535/avast-https-scanning)  or [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82285/are-the-certificates-from-skype-click-to-call-and-avast-web-mail-shield-any) over at security.stackexchange.com

**Problem:**

Because the Avast-Certificate is (of course) not trusted by GlassFish and was not added to Glassfish at installation of Avast, the SSL connection can not be established

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Add the Avast-Certificate to GlassFishs list of valid certificates (thats what the questioner has done)
2. Disable this feature of Avast (Settings -> Active Protection -> E-Mail-Protection)